# Semantic UI dropdown not setting value after selecting option

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, formik

I am using React semantic ui. I am rendering a dropdown in Fieldset. I have written code such that, once a option is selected, the options is updated such that the selected option is removed from the list. **But when I select an option from the dropdown, the selected value is not displayed, rather it shows empty.**

Here is my code:
This is my dropdown code:

```
<Dropdown
name={`rows.${index}.mainField`}
className={"dropdown fieldDropdown"}
widths={2}
placeholder="Field"
fluid
selection  
options={mainFieldOptions}
value={row.mainField}
onChange={(e, { value }) => {
     setFieldValue(`rows.${index}.mainField`, value)
     updateDropDownOptions(value)                               
     }
  }                                                            
/>
```

My options:

```
let mainField = [
    { key: "org", text: "org", value: "org" },
    { key: "role", text: "role", value: "role" },
    { key: "emailId", text: "emailId", value: "emailId" },
]
```

Also, I have:

```
const [mainFieldOptions, setMainFieldOptions] = useState(mainField)
```

And,

```
  const updateDropDownOptions = (value:any) => {
        let updatedOptions: { key: string; text: string; value: string }[] = []
        mainFieldOptions.forEach(option => {
            if(option.key != value){
                updatedOptions.push({ key:option.key , text:option.key, value:option.key  })
            }
        })
        setMainFieldOptions(updatedOptions)
        console.log("mainfield", mainField)
    }
```

In onChange, if I dont call updateDropDownOptions() method, the dropdown value is set. But when I call the method, its giving blank value. Please help.

Comment: when you are selecting an option did you check whether the value is getting changed in the Formik ? .

Comment: If i do console.log(value), in onChange, the selected value is printed

Comment: That is not formik value , that is the value returned to you by the select component . Can you check the Formik state whether it is getting updated when you select an option ? . What do you get in `{row.mainField}` when you select an option ?

Comment: Not getting anythin in {row.mainField}. Its empty

Comment: can you add a sandbox with your current code ? .

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-ls1ox?file=/example.js

This is the sandbox. Main intention is, when a new row is added, the option selected in the first row should not be there for the second row options.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234802/discussion-between-shyam-and-chaitra-d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few changes required in your code,

1. You are pushing the entire initialValues when you are adding a row which is an [{}] but you need to push only `{}` so change your code to `initialValues[0]` in your push method.
2. Its not needed to maintain a additional state for the options. You can filter the options based on the selected option in other rows which is available in the `values.rows` .

Util for filtering the options

```
const getMainFieldOptions = (rows, index) => {
  const selectedOptions = rows.filter((row, rowIndex) => rowIndex !== index);

  const filteredOptions = mainField.filter(mainFieldOption => !selectedOptions.find(selectedOption => mainFieldOption.value === selectedOption.mainField));
  return filteredOptions;
}
```

Call this util when rendering each row

```
values.rows.length > 0 &&
                values.rows.map((row, index) => {
                  const  mainFieldOptions = getMainFieldOptions(values.rows, index);
```

[Working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-df29l?file=/example.js)